# How make LaTeX interpret each line as a new line within an environment?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, multicol

I have  list of file names in a `multicol` environment. I can use sort commands on them when needed e.g. (`sort -u`).

I would like to temporarily make LaTeX recognize a single-newline (`\n`) as a new line. Normally LaTeX recognizes only two newlines (`\n\n`) as a new line.

The purpose is to get a nice list of file names without using a tabular environment. Multicols automatically determines the ideal height of the list based on the count of items and number of columns.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
JPEG
JPEG2000
PDF
PNG
PPM
TIFF
XBM
ZIP
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

## Current Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Comment: Try \obeylines. If you don't like it, try \obeycr.

Comment: `\obeylines` is the answer, which makes a newline a paragraph break (which is also what a blank line signifies: not a newline)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `\obeylines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\obeylines
JPEG
JPEG2000
PDF
PNG
PPM
TIFF
XBM
ZIP
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, remove the mention to `\obeycr` that isn't relevant.

Comment: @egreg Why is `\obeycr` not relevant? It seems to me that it *could* be if I were using a carriage return, no? (by the way, `\obeylines` is what I used of course)

Comment: @macmadness86 `\obeycr`  should be used only in connection with tables (but it's better not using it).

Comment: Surely \obeycr is relevant.  What if you don't want a paragraph indent at the start of each line?